# Why AWS Step Function retries even if state hasn't failed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

In my step function I've added a retry on all failure -

```
"Retry": [
  {
    "ErrorEquals": [
      "States.ALL"
    ],
    "IntervalSeconds": 2,
    "MaxAttempts": 2,
    "BackoffRate": 2
  }
]
```

This state executes several tasks using different task managers. This state retries 2 more times even if the state hasn't failed(haven't found any error trace in lambda execution). The step function execution shows some retries -

[image]

Notice that `Original execution` seems failed. But it doesn't mention any reason.

As I said this state does different things using different manager. For other managers I don't see any retries. Only for a particular manager it retries. And I haven't found any error in the original execution of that manager. Here is the lambda execution logs -

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: The step function won't retry if there isn't any error. For those cases where you didn't get any retries, if the lambda execution was successful then it won't be retried.

Comment: I've checked the lambda execution, it started and ended well. Haven't seen any error in the log. Also if you check the `Reason` of failure of the `Original execution` it shows nothing. Is there any other issue that causes this retry?

Comment: Can you show the logs too? Make sure that the logs that you are checking are correct. Sometimes one log group can contains multiple execution results.

Comment: Does the next step after this expect a specific output? If not, the state execution will fail because it didn't receive the appropriate output. Even if that's not the case then will probably need a reproducible code of your step function to debug further.

Comment: could you enable the stepfn logging and check that plz?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the problem. After successfully completing the lambda execution the state is actually waiting for `taskToken`. And the external process that should send that token back was sending as task_failed. That caused the `originalExecution` failed and step function just did it's job(retrying).

**Take Away:**

If step function execution failed without any reason, check if it is waiting for some external process that should mark the execution as failed/success.